# Find the general solution to

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution to: $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(
>  x^3\frac{du}{dx}\right)=0.$$

What I did was integrate twice and I got $$u(x)= c_2 - \frac{c_1}{2x^2}.$$

But the answer is $$u(x)=c_1 + \frac{c_2}{x^2}.$$

And similary they have the solution to $\frac1r\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{du}{dr}\right)=0$
as $u(r)=c_1+c_2\ln(r)$.

How did they get those answers?

Comment: $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary, so those two solutions are equivalent.

Comment: @Kaster I redid the problem like four times trying to figure out why they had that general solution. -__- Thank you for clearing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their $c_1$ is equal to your $c_2$. Their $c_2$ is equal to $-\frac12$ times your $c_1$.

In other words, we can manipulate arbitrary constants as we find convenient.

Comment: Oh, and Kaster beat me to it in a comment :/

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question, go ahead and take derivatives of $r\frac{du}{dr}$ as follows:
$$
\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\bigg(r\frac{du}{dr}\bigg)=0
$$
$$
\frac{1}{r}\bigg(\frac{du}{dr}+r\frac{d^2u}{dr^2}\bigg)=0
$$
Now if we let $\frac{du}{dr}=\dot{u}$ and $\frac{d^2u}{dr^2}=\ddot{u}$, then
$$
\frac{\dot{u}}{r}+\ddot{u}=0
$$This simplifies to
$$
-\frac{1}{r}=\frac{\ddot{u}}{\dot{u}}=\frac{d}{dr}ln \dot{u}
$$or
$$
d(ln \dot{u})=-\frac{dr}{r}
$$which integrates to
$$
ln\dot{u}=lnr^{-1}+lnC_2
$$or
$$
\dot{u}=\frac{C_2}{r}
$$Integrating again gives you the answer.
$$
u=C_1+C_2lnr
$$